# More elegant way to check 3 conditions in php?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have got 3 tennis courts which you can reserve. Now I need to check which court is reserved. This is very messy in php.
I need to check:

Is court 1 reserved? If yes is court 2 reserved? If yes is court 3 reserved?... You get the point

Here is my code:

```
if ( $counter != 0 ) {
    if ( $counter2 != 0 ) {
        if ( $counter3 != 0 ) {
            //Alle Plätze besetzt
            ?>
            <td>"R"</td>
            <td>"R"</td>
            <td class="td-border-right">"R"</td>
            <?php
        } else {
            //PLatz 1 u 2 besetzt, 3 nicht
            ?>
            <td>"R"</td>
            <td>"R"</td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <?php
        }
    } else if ( $counter3 != 0 ) {
        //PLatz 1 u 3besetzt, 2 nicht besetzt
        ?>
        <td>"R"</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="td-border-right">"R"</td>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <td>"R"</td>
        <td>"R"</td>
        <td> class="td-border-right"></td>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    if ( $counter2 != 0 ) {
        if ( $counter3 != 0 ) {
            ?>
            <td></td>
            <td>"R"</td>
            <td class="td-border-right">"R"</td>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <td></td>
            <td>"R"</td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        if ( $counter3 != 0 ) {
            ?>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right">"R"</td>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

counter 1,2 and 3 are just placeholders for the moment.

Comment: There are different loops in each language. `for($courts as $court) { *** logic *** }`should work. But ifs, not worse here in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courts can be treated individually.

```
<td><?php echo ($counter != 0)? 'R' : '' ?></td>
<td><?php echo ($counter2 != 0)? 'R' : '' ?></td>
<td class="td-border-right"><?php echo ($counter3 != 0)? 'R' : '' ?></td>
```

Comment: I think OP is probably new to programming, so I wouldn't confuse him/her with trigraphs for now, but this is, in essence, the correct solution and the right way to approach the problem. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an array for all counters and loop through each counter.

```
$counters = array( $counter1, $counter2, $counter3 );
foreach ( $counters as $counter ){
    if ( $counter != 0 ) {
        //code goes here;
    }
    else {
        //code goes here;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this:

```
$counter1 = 0;
$counter2 = 0;
$counter3 = 1;

if($counter1 === 0) {
    
    echo 'Its taken';
    
    if($counter2 === 0) {
        
        echo 'Its taken';
        
        if($counter3 === 0) {
            echo 'Its taken';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Its free!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Its free!';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Its free!';
}
```